# how to have an javascript array in the formal parameter list

Tags: javascript

How can array be passed into a JavaScript function whose parameters should be a JavaScript array
How to have  an array declared in formal parameter list of the JavaScript function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript variables are not typed, and so there is no possibility to declare them as arrays either. Just use the normal parameter syntax:

```
function takesAnArray(arr) {
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        console.log(arr[i]);
}
takesAnArray( [1, 2, 3] );
```

Comment: Is there any way in which an array can be passed into a single js variable? can it be passed separate separate only??

Comment: The array `[1, 2, 3]` *is* passed into the single variable `arr`. Or didn't I understand your question?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like:

```
var yourArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
function myfunction(a, b, c, d, e){
    console.log(a);//1
    //...
    console.log(e);//5
}

//then you pass the array items each as a parameter like
myfunction.apply(null, yourArray);
```

There is a irrelevant point here about the `null` parameter, but as far as it is relevant to the `apply` it is worth noticing. The point is if you pass it with a object, that object would serve as the `this` object in your function's body.